# Expression statements in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can an assignment expression be an expression statement if it stands alone? 
For example is the statement `a = b * 2 ;` an expression statement?

Comment: It is an expression statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is an expression statement. `=` and `*` are operators, and `a = b * 2` is an expression.